# Why clearInterval() doesn't work when Boostrap 5 Modal is shown?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap5-modal

Need some help here. I feel my code is correct but it doesn't work. I want my `setInterval()` to stop as soon as I click on a Modal button but it doesn't, the screen turns black (background of Modal):

I have the following:

```
    var myTimer=null;

    function startTimer() {
      myTimer = setInterval(function () {
        //some function that updates every second
      }, 1000);
    };

    function stopTimer() {
      clearInterval(myTimer);
      myTimer=null;
    };


    startTimer(); // call startTimer() when loading the page


   {% for job in table %}   
      {% if job.status == "ok" %}

        $(document).on('show.bs.modal', '#jobModal{{ job.id }}', function (e) {
          console.log('works modal show'); //it prints
          stopTimer();
          console.log('after modal show'); // it prints
      });

        $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '#jobModal{{ job.id }}', function (e) {
          console.log('works modal hide'); //step not reached because screens turns black
          startTimer();
          console.log('after modal hide'); //step not reached...
        });
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

I use a Django loop. What is interesting is that I'm able to print in the console the lines before and after calling stopTimer(), but the screen after a few milliseconds turns black with some opacity (the usual background of a modal bootstrap). What is wrong? I would like to stop the `setInterval()`  so I could see the modal form when I click on the modal button. Thanks.

Comment: Just curious: do you get the same issue when you listen to other Bootstrap modal events e.g. `hide.bs.modal` instead of `hidden.bs.modal`. I am just wondering if the event is being fired at all.

Comment: BTW I noticed Bootstrap's own example use the element ID i.e. `$('#myModal').on()` instead of `$(document).on()`

Comment: Here's you code tested, works fine: https://jsbin.com/jilidunovu/1/edit?js,output You should show us the generated HTML instead of the django template, ideally as [mre]

Comment: Thanks. however, the modal window kept freezing. I fixed it by adding `stop()` below `stopTimer()`. Maybe it is a django problem in my code, forcing the stop helps but I'm still confused. I may need to break down the code to understand why it keeps freezing. I wonder if adding `stop()` is ok or I should avoid that, it solved the problem though.

Comment: @IrfanullahJan You are right, however `$(document)` worked better than `$('#id')` in my case. The latter didn't even print the console.log, so it was not called properly. I don't know why.